# Как парсить, если есть пропуски?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, request

При парсинге ссылок одного элемента находит сайты, а в цикле (т.к. есть пропущенные значения) выдает ошибку. В столбце site есть пропуски.

```
for item in companies:
    dict_comp['title'] = item.find('div', attrs={'class':'similar-item__title'}).get_text(strip=True)
    dict_comp['descriptions'] = item.find('div', attrs = {'class':'similar-item__description'}).get_text(strip = True)
    dict_comp['site'] = item.find('div', attrs = {'class':'site'}).get_text(strip = True)
    dict_comp['phone'] = item.find('div', attrs = {'class':'phone'}).get_text(strip = True)
    dict_comp['adress'] = item.find('div', attrs = {'class':'similar-item__adrss-item'}).get_text(strip = True)
    list_comp.append(dict_comp.copy())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. метод `.find()` в случае ненахождения возвращает значение `None`, сначала сохраните его результат в переменной — например `found` — и затем тестируйте этот результат, т.е вместо одной команды

```
dict_comp['site'] = item.find('div', attrs = {'class':'site'}).get_text(strip = True)
```

примените эти:

```
found = item.find('div', attrs={'class':'site'}).get_text(strip=True)
if found:
    dict_comp['site'] = found 
else:
    dict_comp['site'] = ""
```

или короче

```
found = item.find('div', attrs={'class':'site'}).get_text(strip=True)
dict_comp['site'] = found or ""
```

(То же самое вы можете сделать для 4 остальных подобных команд чтобы заранее предотвратить ошибки.)

---

Красивее решение:

Сначала создайте список (или кортеж) пар

```
KEY_CLASS_PAIRS = [('title', 'similar-item__title'), 
                   ('descriptions', 'similar-item__description'), 
                   ('site', 'site'), 
                   ('phone', 'phone'), 
                   ('adress', 'similar-item__adrss-item'),
                  ]
```

и затем весь ваш цикл может сократиться до такого:

```
for item in companies:
    for key, cls in KEY_CLASS_PAIRS:
        found = item.find('div', attrs={'class': f'{cls}'}).get_text(strip=True)
        dict_comp[key] = found or ""
    list_comp.append(dict_comp.copy())
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все равно не получается, как только не пробовала, выдает ошибку 
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? И find и find_all все равно ошибка. Пробовала через исключения except attributeerror выдает пустые значения

Comment: @Inna Kh, в той части кода, которую вы привели, нет применения метода `.find_all()`. Ни в моем коде его нет, значит, я вас совсем не понимаю. Я точно ответил на ваш вопрос из вашего заголовка, даже сделал ваш код более красивым. Я думаю, что вы бы могла мое усилие и время оценить принятием моего ответа (клик на галочку налево от него). - Затем вы можете создать другой, новый вопрос. В нем вы точнее объясните, в чем ваша проблема, и приведите соответствующий код для тех, которые вам будут хотеть помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Inna Kh, спасибо за принятие моего ответа.